# Get payload that starts with 0 in Node Red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am trying to get payload data that has the following structure:

[image: payload]

But when i write my variable like this:

```
var credit = msg.payload.weatherdata.credit.0;
return credit;
```

I get an error saying "Unexpected Number", because javascript thinks it's an number in the payload message.

How do I retrive my data from the payload when I have a 0 in the payload?

Comment: credit is a array not a object, var credit = msg.payload.weatherdata.credit[0];

Comment: I realised that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think it through. It's an array therefore it must be in this format .credit[0].